# Difference CLR and CLI and how to call those from pure C

Tags: c#, .net, c, clr, command-line-interface

Could somebody tell me what the difference between CLR and CLI is in it's basic functionallity but most important would be which one of them is better?

---

All I got so far is that using the `ICLRRuntimeHost` Interface does not allow me to return anything else than an `int` and the only allowed parameter is a `LPCWSTR` (see [ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164411%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

At this point I am wondering if one could/would allocate memory e.g. for a `struct` in his C program, give a pointer as a `LPCWSTR string` to `ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain` and translates this pointer back into that `struct` on the other side to work on that `struct`. I don't get it how one can work with the limitation of this signator for each function: `int fncname(string param);`

---

I took a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes) tutorial but I don't get it how calling C++/CLI from a C program works and how I could return complex objects or anything more complex than an `int`.

---

And could somebody please show me HOW I can use **CLI** within C? I can't seem to find some lines of code that would show how that would work.

---

Comment: C++/CLI allows you to create mixed mode dlls. That is you can write a dll that is part native and part .net (CLR). The trick is to write a native unsafe C++ part, that calls the .net (CLR) part. You then expose the native methods via something like `COM`, which your C can directly call. However, you have to note that the point where you move data from managed to native there is a MASSIVE performance hit as you have to copy the data across. Large complex data structures will be very slow. An alternative would be to use direct shared memory. Given you are using C, that might be the way to go.

Comment: Yeah but all I see is this `ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain` function that only takes a `LPCWSTR` as argument and that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass and return complex data in CLI. CLI is an intermediate layer. when you pass data from a managed code(.NET) to native code (c,c++) you need a intermediate layer which will take responsibility of managed to native object and vice verse conversation because managed objects are managed by Garbage collector and native objects are managed by programmer (need to delete when created).

In C++/CLI there are two type of class. 1) Manged class 2) Native class. A managed class is defined as :

```
public ref class ManagedClass
{
NativeObject* native;
ManagedObject^ mObject;
}
```

This can contain managed and native object. So in this class you create a managed/native class object which is replica of native/managed object (in terms of containing data and method). The basic data in any object is either another object or basic primitive data which can be easily converted. You have to take care of objects only.

Suppose you want to execute C++ method form .NET. Your c++ code has an object called NativeClass and your c++ method return this native object. You can't pass this object directly to .NET layer. So you will store that object instance in variable **native** of above class **ManagedClass**. Note that you can access native as well as managed object in CLI layer. Now you create a manged object class in CLI which will be exact replica of native class in term of containing data. Now you copy all date from Native object to managed object and assign that managed object instance to variable **mObject**. Now you can pass this variable **mObject** to .NET layer because this is Manged object.

Similar approach can be used when you pass Managed object to Native method.

You can go through this PDF to know more about C++/CLI.

http://asawicki.info/Download/Productions/Publications/CPP_CLI_tutorial.pdf

---

**UPDATE:**

I will recommend you to first go through the PDF. Below is a simple example how this conversion happens. **NativeObject** is C++ object (You can also have C **struct** instaed of Class) and **ManagedObject** is C# object and **CLIInterface** is used to provide interface.

```
public ref class CLIInterface
{
private:
    NativeObject* native;
    ManagedObject^ mObject;
public:
    CLIInterface(NativeObject* nativeObj){
        native = nativeObj;
        mObject = gcnew ManagedObject(nativeObj);
    }
    string getNativeMessage();
    int getNaiveID();
    String^ getManagedMessage();
    int getmanagedID();
}
```

Native class:(C++ Object or C struct and can be used in CLI)

```
public class NativeObject
{
private:
    int id;
    string msg;
public:
    string getMessage(){return msg;}
    int getID(){return id;}
}
```

Managed class: (C# object and you can use it in CLI)

```
public ref class ManagedObject
{
private:
    NativeObject* native;
public:
    ManagedObject(NativeObject* obj){
        native = obj;
    }
    String^ getMessage(){
        convertNativeToCLI(native->getMessage()); //you can use marshaling to implement convertNativeToCLI method. 
    }
    int getID(){
        return native->getID();
    }
}
```

You can use Managed class object and CLIInterface from C# code and you can use Native Object in C++ code. I hope this will help. You can also go to Microsoft's C++/CLI documentation.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. Thad PDF looks interesting. But does this work for pure C as well?

Comment: what exactly you want to use in Pure C? Is it a .NET library or something else. Can you explain what exactly you want to do with CLI in Pure C?

Comment: Well I have here a server written in good old C (no .NET involved or anything near it) and some C# .NET libraries that this server is supposed to use. At the moment all I got is the `ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain` method of the `ICLRRuntimeHost` interface. But this just allows me to pass `LPCWSTR` as argument and return an `int` nothing more, nothing less. I am looking for a way  to use this C# library in C and maybr return at least structs or pass structs as arguments.

Comment: You can create a CLI layer for C# libraries. The core idea will be same as i have mentioned above. And yes you can use it in pure C.

Comment: I still don't get it how I then would call those functions. Could you show me that interface somewhere that later on allows me what I described?