# C++/CLI object casting

Tags: c#, pointers, c++-cli

sort of new in CLI and wrapper making and got a question about pointers and object casting.

Header of my native code:

```
class Telegram : public Message
{
  public:
     Telegram(const Telegram& tele);
     int variablesX;
     int variablesY;
}
```

Source of the native code:

```
Telegram::Telegram(const Telegram& tele) : Message(tele.lenght)
{
   variablesX = tele.variablesX;
   variablesY = tele.variablesY;
}
```

And the trying to get into managed code:
header:

```
   public ref class TelegramWrapper : public MessageWrapper
    {
       public:
        TelegramWrapper(eoTelegramWrapper^ tel):
       private:
        Telegram *myTelegram;
    }
```

source:

```
TelegramWrapper::TelegramWrapper(TelegramWrapper^ tel) : MessageWrapper(tel->lenght)
{
   myTelegram = new Telegram(reinterpreter_cast<Telegram%>(tel));
}
```

Can compile, no error just in the C# application cannot use because i receive the error: 'TelegramWrapper telegram' is not supported by the language.
I have tried safe_cast too but because of the pointer differencies it is not possible. 
How could type casting the TelegramWrapper object into Telegram?
Thanks for the answers in advance!

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593624/difference-clr-and-cli-and-how-to-call-those-from-pure-c/21602981#21602981

Comment: You cannot cast a managed class object to a native class object, their underlying implementation and storage is drastically different.   You *must* convert, create a new Telegram object from the wrapper data you have.  Do note that native code also can never create a Telegram object, you must add another constructor or factory method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not all familiar with C++/CLI, but if you're trying to make a wrapper then you should wrap instead of cast (unless I'm missing something obvious).

```
public ref class TelegramWrapper : public MessageWrapper
{
    public:
        TelegramWrapper(TelegramWrapper^ tel);
        TelegramWrapper(const &Telegram tel);
    private:
        Telegram *myTelegram;

    property int MyVariablesX {
        public: int get { return myTelegram->someVariablesX; }
        public: void set(int value) { myTelegram->someVariablesX = value; }
    }

    property int MyVariablesY {
        public: int get { return myTelegram->someVariablesY; }
        public: void set(int value) { myTelegram->someVariablesY = value; }
    }
};

TelegramWrapper::TelegramWrapper(TelegramWrapper^ tel) : MessageWrapper(tel->Lenght)
{
    myTelegram = tel->myTelegram;
}

TelegramWrapper::TelegramWrapper(const &Telegram tel) : MessageWrapper(tel.lenght)
{
    myTelegram = tel;
}
```